# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, goerli, sepolia, etherjs

I'm new to Solidity and ether js. I'm stuck with error below in VSCode. Can anybody help explain what this error means and advise how to fix this? Thank you so much!

##### ERROR BELOW:

```
(node:5884) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners ad
ded to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\saint\Downloads\DATA\Solidity\sol workspace\ethers-scripts\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\provi
ders\provider-etherscan.js:294
            if (!message.match(/revert/i) && message.match(/insufficient funds/i)) {
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')
    at EtherscanProvider._checkError (C:\Users\saint\Downloads\DATA\Solidity\sol workspace\ethers-scripts\
node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-etherscan.js:294:26)
    at EtherscanProvider._perform (C:\Users\saint\Downloads\DATA\Solidity\sol workspace\ethers-scripts\nod
e_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-etherscan.js:422:33)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async #perform (C:\Users\saint\Downloads\DATA\Solidity\sol workspace\ethers-scripts\node_modules\et
hers\lib.commonjs\providers\abstract-provider.js:265:16)
    at async EtherscanProvider.estimateGas (C:\Users\saint\Downloads\DATA\Solidity\sol workspace\ethers-sc
ripts\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\abstract-provider.js:619:42)
    at async FallbackProvider._translatePerform (C:\Users\saint\Downloads\DATA\Solidity\sol workspace\ethe
rs-scripts\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-fallback.js:291:24)
    at async C:\Users\saint\Downloads\DATA\Solidity\sol workspace\ethers-scripts\node_modules\ethers\lib.c
ommonjs\providers\provider-fallback.js:356:32
```

##### CODE BELOW

```js
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const sender_pvt_key = ".."; //some private key I inputted
const receiver_address = "..."; //some address I inputted
const amount = "0.00022";

let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider("sepolia");
let sender_wallet = new ethers.Wallet(sender_pvt_key, provider);

//console.log(sender_wallet.address);
let tx = {
    to: receiver_address,
    value: ethers.parseEther(amount),
   };

sender_wallet.sendTransaction(tx).then((result) => {
 console.log("txHash", result.hash);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE to above question!

So after several attempts, it seems I have found the culprit. For some reason, the network provider name ("sepolia") I entered with getDefaultProvider function does not get recognized when I run above code.

SOLUTION:
I've learned a simple hack from this [thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/148969/goerli-ethers-js-6-3-api-key-unsupported-network-and-403-server-errors) - replace argument with a public RPC URL through this [site](https://chainlist.org/chain/11155111). Took me a few times to figure out the exact Sepolia testnet that matches my Metamask config but in the end, the tx did work just fine!